# Converting ts object to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to transform my `ts` object to `data.frame` object. My MWE is given below:

### Code

```
set.seed(12345)
dat <- ts(data=runif(n=10, min=50, max=100), frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(index(dat)), Y = melt(dat)$value)
```

### Output

```
         date        Y
1  1975-05-14 86.04519
2  1975-05-14 93.78866
3  1975-05-14 88.04912
4  1975-05-15 94.30623
5  1975-05-15 72.82405
6  1975-05-15 58.31859
7  1975-05-15 66.25477
8  1975-05-16 75.46122
9  1975-05-16 86.38526
10 1975-05-16 99.48685
```

I have lost my quarters in date columns. How can I figure out the problem?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

How about

```
data.frame(Y=as.matrix(dat), date=time(dat))
```

This returns

```
          Y    date
1  86.04519 1959.25
2  93.78866 1959.50
3  88.04912 1959.75
4  94.30623 1960.00
5  72.82405 1960.25
6  58.31859 1960.50
7  66.25477 1960.75
8  75.46122 1961.00
9  86.38526 1961.25
10 99.48685 1961.50
```

Comment: (+1): Thanks @MrFlick `as.Date(time(dat))` is more appropriate and did the trick.

Comment: The code `as.Date(time(dat))` does not work for me. I am getting the error: `Error in as.Date.default(time(dat)) : do not know how to convert 'time(dat)' to class “Date”`.

Comment: @djhurio specifying `zoo::as.Date` helps

Answer (score 18):

`yearmon` (from `zoo`) allows creating `Date` objects.

```
> dat <- ts(data=runif(n=10, min=50, max=100), frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
> data.frame(Y=as.matrix(dat), date=as.Date(as.yearmon(time(dat))))
          Y       date
1  51.72677 1959-04-01
2  57.61867 1959-07-01
3  86.78425 1959-10-01
4  50.05683 1960-01-01
5  69.56017 1960-04-01
6  73.12473 1960-07-01
7  69.40720 1960-10-01
8  70.12426 1961-01-01
9  58.94818 1961-04-01
10 97.58294 1961-07-01
```

Comment: or `data.frame(date = as.Date(as.yearmon(time(dat))), Y = coredata(dat))`

Comment: Does not work for me. Had to use `as.Date(paste(1, zoo::as.yearmon(time(dat))), format = "%d %b %Y")`.

Comment: Nowadays, I believe that `broom` makes it easy, you could simply `broom::tidy(dat)`.

Comment: @WilsonFreitas, nope. `broom::tidy(dat)` does not help. It just converts `dat` to `tibble`. No date conversation is done.

Comment: @djhurio, I think you changed the code in my comment introducing an error into the working code.   The non-working code likely used `zoo::as.yearmon` rather than `library(zoo)` introducing the error which is due to `as.Date.yearmon` not being found.  The code in my comment does work assuming the setup in the answer which in turn assumes `library(zoo)` was issued.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, you are right. Thanks! I confirm, this is a working solution: `library(zoo);data.frame(date = as.Date(as.yearmon(time(dat))), Y = coredata(dat))`.

Answer (score 10):

The package timetk has several conversion functions. In your case:

```
dat <- ts(data=runif(n=10, min=50, max=100), frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))

timetk::tk_tbl(dat)

    # A tibble: 10 x 2
           index    value
   <S3: yearqtr>    <dbl>
 1       1959 Q2 86.04519
 2       1959 Q3 93.78866
 3       1959 Q4 88.04912
 4       1960 Q1 94.30623
 5       1960 Q2 72.82405
 6       1960 Q3 58.31859
 7       1960 Q4 66.25477
 8       1961 Q1 75.46122
 9       1961 Q2 86.38526
10       1961 Q3 99.48685
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems that converting from `xts` objects seems to be both reliable and well documented. Below works and with the new date column in date / yearqtr class.

```
library(xts)
datx <- as.xts(dat)
df   <- data.frame(date=index(datx), coredata(datx))
```

Checking class of `date`:

```
class(df$date)
[1] "yearqtr"
```

And result:

```
print(df)

  date coredata.datx.
1  1959 Q2       86.04519
2  1959 Q3       93.78866
3  1959 Q4       88.04912
4  1960 Q1       94.30623
5  1960 Q2       72.82405
6  1960 Q3       58.31859
7  1960 Q4       66.25477
8  1961 Q1       75.46122
9  1961 Q2       86.38526
10 1961 Q3       99.48685
```

Answer (score 1):

Package 'ggpp' provides function `try_data_frame()` (implemented using packages 'xts', 'zoo' and 'lubridate') that does the conversion in a single step. (This function is used in package 'ggpp' to implement a `ggplot()` method for time series, and returns the time index converted into a class that packages 'ggplot2' and 'scales' can use: `Date` or `POSIXct`.)

```r
set.seed(12345)
dat.ts <- ts(data=runif(n=10, min=50, max=100), frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))

library(ggpp)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggpp'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     annotate
dat.df <- try_data_frame(dat.ts)

str(dat.df)
#> 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ time  : Date, format: "1959-05-01" "1959-08-01" ...
#>  $ dat.ts: num  86 93.8 88 94.3 72.8 ...

dat.df
#>          time   dat.ts
#> 1  1959-05-01 86.04519
#> 2  1959-08-01 93.78866
#> 3  1959-11-01 88.04912
#> 4  1960-02-01 94.30623
#> 5  1960-05-01 72.82405
#> 6  1960-08-01 58.31859
#> 7  1960-11-01 66.25477
#> 8  1961-02-01 75.46122
#> 9  1961-05-01 86.38526
#> 10 1961-08-01 99.48685
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

See `help(try_data_frame())` for the details on how to set the names of columns or alter the way in which dates or times are handled.

Answer (score 1):

My function `ts_as_tibble()` can be used.

```r
# Install `timeplyr` using the below code.
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")

library(timeplyr)

ts_as_tibble(dat)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>     time value
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1959.  86.0
#>  2 1960.  93.8
#>  3 1960.  88.0
#>  4 1960   94.3
#>  5 1960.  72.8
#>  6 1960.  58.3
#>  7 1961.  66.3
#>  8 1961   75.5
#>  9 1961.  86.4
#> 10 1962.  99.5

# Multiple series
ts_as_tibble(EuStockMarkets)
#> # A tibble: 7,440 x 3
#>    group  time value
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 DAX   1991. 1629.
#>  2 DAX   1992. 1614.
#>  3 DAX   1992. 1607.
#>  4 DAX   1992. 1621.
#>  5 DAX   1992. 1618.
#>  6 DAX   1992. 1611.
#>  7 DAX   1992. 1631.
#>  8 DAX   1992. 1640.
#>  9 DAX   1992. 1635.
#> 10 DAX   1992. 1646.
#> # i 7,430 more rows
```

When the data contains multiple series, it is always converted to long format.
Currently `ts`, `mts`, `xts` and `timeSeries` objects are supported.

The advantage of always returning it to long-format is that it can easily be passed to `ggplot`.

```r
eu_stock <- ts_as_tibble(EuStockMarkets)
time_ggplot(eu_stock, time, value, group)
```

[image]