# R: Converting "mts", "ts", "matrix" object to data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have following matrix:

```
                   value1             value2              value3 
2001 Q1            9.25                26.45               26.64 
2001 Q2            9.25                25.67               26.50 
2001 Q3            9.50                23.15               23.49 
2001 Q4           10.00                20.30               20.43
```

I confirm its a matrix:

```
 class(dataMat)
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

What I am little confuse about the column that has year and the quarter when I write to file using zoo, I don't see the year and the quarter at all. Due to this I tried to convert this matrix in to data.frame. Unfortunately Year and Quarter disappear instead I get numerical index in data frame.

```
data.frame(dataMat)
```

How do I convert above data matrix to a data frame.

In addition I am little bit confuse about this data structure: If I do fallowing I get 4 quarters which tells me underline data structure has some notion of time series.

```
> dataMat[,1]
      Qtr1  Qtr2  Qtr3  Qtr4
2001  9.25  9.25  9.50 10.00
```

Comment: can you `dput()` `dataMat`?

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353002/converting-ts-object-to-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue seems to be that the first row is actually the row names. You can extract them using `rownames(dataMat)`.