# Convert ts object to dataframe with Date/POSIXct column (base R)

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time-series

I have a time series that I want to transform to a dataframe with column(s) containing the values and one Date/ POSIXct column with the ttime. Reproducible example:

```
data_ts <- ts(matrix(1:14, ncol= 2), start= c(2000, 1), frequency= 6)
```

Expected output is:

```
data_df <- data.frame(Series_1= 1:7, Series_2= 8:14, Date= seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), length.out= nrow(data_ts)*2, by= "month")[seq(1, nrow(data_ts)*2, 2)])

data_df
Series_1 Series_2       Date
1        1        8 2000-01-01
2        2        9 2000-03-01
3        3       10 2000-05-01
4        4       11 2000-07-01
5        5       12 2000-09-01
6        6       13 2000-11-01
7        7       14 2001-01-01
```

In this example the `frequency` is `6` and start is at `c(2000, 1)` but in my use case I do not know those parameters in beforehand. In fact, the `frequency` could also be so big that I refers to hours/ minutes or seconds (`frequency= 365*24*60*60`, for example). If frequency is in years/ month/ weeks/ days class `Date` is enough but for hours/ minutes/ seconds the column must changes, of course (to `POSIXct`). So I am trying a general solution. I want it to be base R.

There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353002/converting-ts-object-to-data-frame) question but the answer has a column with dates as decimal numbers. Instead I need a actual Date/PSIXct column.

Comment: If you are okay with lubridate `transform(as.data.frame(data_ts), Date = as.Date(date_decimal(as.numeric(time(data_ts)))))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks but I am asked to stick to base R by my supervisor.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck We can simply change frequency from 365*24*60*60 to 365.25*24*60*60 to handle leap years (see [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/)). Anyway, depending on context Rob Hyndman also suggests to use [frequency=7](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/) for daily data and in this case my attempts don't make any sense because my approach always refers to year units and dates. I gues I have to rephrase the question. But to restrict the frequency to (multiple of) months is not an option.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Wheter it is okay to use 365.25*24*60*60 instead of 365*24*60*60 because of leap years or not because " ts only works with a fixed/constant number of points per year" is something you would have to discuss with Rob Hyndman I guess. I stick to his description because otherwise I see no solution how to define days/hours/minutes/seconds in a year. And yes, "if it has an annual frequency you can't just say it is 7". I meant that with "depending on context Rob Hyndman also suggests to use frequency=7 for daily data".

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Take a minute and visit the link. He writes "I’ve had several emails recently asking how to forecast daily data in R. Unless the time series is very long, the easiest approach is to simply set the frequency attribute to 7." See [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/) and for daily/ hourly/... data [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/). And yes, he refers to ts (and msts)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Why is it garbage? @"what you are reading does not represent authoritative information on ts": "[Robin John Hyndman FAA FASSA (born 2 May 1967) is an Australian statistician known for his work on forecasting and time series. He is Professor of Statistics at Monash University..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_J._Hyndman). I think he should know. He is also one of the authors of [tsibble](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsibble/index.html)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I provide you clear references with clear quotes as "Unless the time series is very long, the easiest approach is to simply set the frequency attribute to 7". You just write that I am wrong. That is not really constructive nor reasonable. Did you consider the option that you misunderstand ts? Anyway, the discussion does not lead anywhere.

Comment: I didn't say what you are reading is garbage. I wrote that if you set things to arbitrary values that don't make sense then it is a case of garbage in/garbage out.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes this is true, if you set arbitrary numbers you get garbage. I provided a source that says the numbers are not arbitrary -> no garbage in, no garbage out. Anyway, your comment was helpful though because I noticed that I can not stick to dates.

Comment: ts requires regularly spaced points.   That is the basis of the class.  You can't have different numbers of points in different years and if the series has an annual period of fluctuation it makes no sense to claim it is 7 days. Those are just the facts.

Comment: I noticed this comment - "Deleting my account because of stackoverflow.com/questions/70476759/…". Just wanted to tell you that you can use a Flag to have your question disassociated from your account, removing the negative reputation impact, so there's no reason to delete your account.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with an approach which uses the `seq` function if the frequency is in full month, weeks or days, choosing the corresponding `by` argument (`"month"`, `"week"` or `"day"`). For cases where frequency is not full month, week or day I calculated to how many seconds the frequency corresponds. For example, a frequency of `365*24` means that we need to go in `60*60=3600` second steps (because `365*24` means hours and `60*60` second steps are hour steps), and so on.

This all gives the following rather long solution, but it works in all cases I've tried so far:

```
ts_to_df <- function(data){
ts_freq <- frequency(data)
# Works for univariate and multivariate time series:
if(is.null(dim(data))){
ts_length <- length(data)
} else{
ts_length <- nrow(data)
}

# For full month.
if(ts_freq %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12)){
n_months <- 12/ ts_freq
first_month <- as.Date(paste(start(data)[1], 
start(data)[2]*n_months-(n_months-1), "1", sep= "/"))
ts_date <- seq(first_month, length.out= ts_length*n_months, by= "month")
ts_date <- ts_date[seq(1, length(ts_date), by= n_months)]

# For full weeks.
} else if(ts_freq == 52){
first_week <- seq(as.Date(paste(start(data)[1], "/1/1", sep="")), length.out= start(data)[2], by= "week")[start(data)[2]]
ts_date <- seq(first_week, length.out= ts_length, by= "week")

# For full days.
} else if(ts_freq == 365 | ts_freq == 366){
first_day <- as.Date(paste(start(data)[1], "/1/", start(data)[2], sep=""))
ts_date <- seq(first_day, length.out= ts_length, by= "day")

# All other cases.
} else{
sec_year <- 365*24*60*60
freq_fraction <- 1/ts_freq
sec_steps <- sec_year*freq_fraction
first_sec <- as.POSIXct(paste(start(data)[1], "-01-01 00:00:01", sep="")) + sec_steps*start(data)[2] - sec_steps
ts_date <- first_sec + sec_steps *0:(ts_length-1)
}

# Make a data.frame.
data_df <- data.frame(as.matrix(data))
data_df$date <- ts_date
data_df
}
```

Applying the function to a `ts` with weeks as frequency:

```
ts_to_df(ts(matrix(1:14, ncol= 2), start= c(2000, 1), frequency= 52))
Series.1 Series.2       date
1        1        8 2000-01-01
2        2        9 2000-01-08
3        3       10 2000-01-15
4        4       11 2000-01-22
5        5       12 2000-01-29
6        6       13 2000-02-05
7        7       14 2000-02-12
```

Now to a `ts` that has minutes as frequency and start from the 10th minute of 2009:

```
ts_to_df(ts(matrix(1:14, ncol= 2), start= c(2009, 10), frequency= 365*24*60))
Series.1 Series.2                date
1        1        8 2009-01-01 00:09:01
2        2        9 2009-01-01 00:10:01
3        3       10 2009-01-01 00:11:01
4        4       11 2009-01-01 00:12:01
5        5       12 2009-01-01 00:13:01
6        6       13 2009-01-01 00:14:01
7        7       14 2009-01-01 00:15:01
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2):

I think easiest way is with tsbox and base R data.frames.

```
library(tsbox)
data_ts = ts(matrix(1:14, ncol= 2), start= c(2000, 1), frequency= 6)

ts_df = ts_df(data_ts)
ts_df = dcast(ts_df, time~id, value.var=value)
```

Output:

```
> ts_dt
         time Series 1 Series 2
1: 2000-01-01        1        8
2: 2000-03-01        2        9
3: 2000-05-01        3       10
4: 2000-07-01        4       11
5: 2000-09-01        5       12
6: 2000-11-01        6       13
7: 2001-01-01        7       14
```

If you would use just base R I don't know a very handy solution, but there are better R coders in this community than me and maybe one knows a solution without dozens of rows.

Update:

**An attempt just with base R. If having months:**

```
data_ts = ts(matrix(1:14, ncol= 2), start= c(2000, 1), frequency= 6)

df_ts = data.frame(data_ts)

df_ts$date = as.numeric(time(data_ts))
df_ts$date = as.Date(paste0(floor(df_ts$date), "-", 
                            sprintf("%02d", 1+round((df_ts$date-floor(df_ts$date))*12)), "-01"))
```

Output:

```
> df_ts
  Series.1 Series.2       date
1        1        8 2000-01-01
2        2        9 2000-03-01
3        3       10 2000-05-01
4        4       11 2000-07-01
5        5       12 2000-09-01
6        6       13 2000-11-01
7        7       14 2001-01-01
```

**If having weeks:**

```
df_ts = data.frame(data_ts)

df_ts$week = as.numeric(time(data_ts))
df_ts$week = paste0(floor(df_ts$week), "-", 
                            sprintf("%02d", 1+round((df_ts$week-floor(df_ts$week))*52)))
```

Output:

```
   Series.1 Series.2    week
1         1       15 2000-01
2         2       16 2000-02
3         3       17 2000-03
4         4       18 2000-04
5         5       19 2000-05
6         6       20 2000-06
7         7       21 2000-07
8         8       22 2000-08
9         9       23 2000-09
10       10       24 2000-10
11       11       25 2000-11
12       12       26 2000-12
13       13       27 2000-13
14       14       28 2000-14
```

**If having days:**

```
data_ts = ts(matrix(1:20, ncol= 2), start= c(2000, 1, 1), frequency= 365)

df_ts = data.frame(data_ts)

df_ts$date = time(data_ts)
df_ts$date = as.Date(paste0(floor(df_ts$date), 
                            "-", 
                            sprintf("%02d", 1+round((df_ts$date-floor(df_ts$date))*365)), 
                            "-01"), "%Y-%j")
```

Output:

```
> df_ts
   Series.1 Series.2       date
1         1       11 2000-01-01
2         2       12 2000-01-02
3         3       13 2000-01-03
4         4       14 2000-01-04
5         5       15 2000-01-05
6         6       16 2000-01-06
7         7       17 2000-01-07
8         8       18 2000-01-08
9         9       19 2000-01-09
10       10       20 2000-01-10
```