# Wrong date format in Time Series object using R studio

Tags: r, date-format

I am composing a time series analysis. The problem occurs when I am trying to plot the object. But first things first. I use an API, to collect my time series data and create my ts object. When I create the ts-object, it is required to indicate the starting date, and the frequency of the data collected. The data are daily, hence I use frequency = 365. As a starting date, I enter

```
min(as.Date(data_collected$timestamp))
```

When I print this, I get the correct format of a date, though when I am trying to plot the time series object with the `plot(ts_object)` I get the following in the x-axis. Do you know how to correct this?

[image]

How can I convert those to normal formatted days like Day/Month/Year?

Comment: How do you plot your plot . Could you show the code?

Comment: I use plot(ts_object) nothing more. If that does not answer your question, I will update my question later on using this information as well.

Comment: What is the type of `tsobject$timestamp`? And of  `min(tsobject$timestamp)`? The fact you need `as.Date()` suggests something might be slightly awry…. But we can’t be sure because your problem is not *reproducible*. Help yourself by helping us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the examples in `help(ts)` the start argument for this function is not expecting a date, rather it expects something like `c(2022, 01)` for year and month (say).

The following is an example that shows the behaviour you are describing.

```
ts_object <- ts(data = rnorm(4000), 
                start = Sys.Date(), # Sys.Date() is a date
                                    # which is not what 
                                    # ts() expects
                frequency = 365)
plot(ts_object)
```

[image: Plot of ts_object]

If I was looking for a plot with pretty date axes, with months I would probably create a data.frame using the method suggested by akrun in the first comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70309640/19553572).

First create the ts_object with `start` defined in a format consistent with the help file:

```
ts_object <- ts(data = rnorm(4000), 
                start = c(as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")),
                          as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%m"))), 
                frequency = 365)
plot(ts_object)
```

[image: plot of ts_object with correct start definition]

```
my_df <- transform(as.data.frame(ts_object), 
                   Date = as.Date(date_decimal(as.numeric(time(ts_object)))))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(my_df[1:600,],
       aes(x = Date,
           y = as.numeric(x))) + # as,numeric(x) to turn x from 'ts' to numeric for plot
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(labels = label_date_short())
```

This plot only shows the first 600 days of data, to show how scales::label_date_short() works.

[image: plot of time-series data with pretty date labels]